# ascent of product of two linear operators

Tags: spectral-theory

Let $S,T: X \rightarrow X$ be two bounded linear operators on a Banach space $X$. Let $ST=TS$.

If asc$(ST$) is finite then is asc$(T)$ finite?

For a bounded linear operator $A$ on a Banach space $X$ ascent of $A$ (denoted by asc$(A)$) is defined as the smallest positive integer $p$ such that ker$A^p=$ ker$A^{p+1}$. If no such integer exists the we set asc$(A)=\infty$

Comment: $S=0$ and $asc(T)=\infty$

Comment: what will be the case if we take $S$ and $T$ to be non-zero operators?